# Using RUnning Value to create a pareto in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008

I am trying to create a Pareto chart for the table below

| Press | Reason | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Broke | 5 |
| B | Broke | 10 |
| C | Broke | 15 |
| D | Broke | 5 |
| E | Broke | 10 |
| F | Broke | 100 |

I am trying to create a pareto using the following:

=RunningValue(Fields!LossQty.Value/Sum(Fields!LossQty.Value, "Conf_Scrap")*100,Sum, Nothing)

But I keep getting the error:
**"The Y expression for the chart has a nested aggregate that specifies a dataset scope. Inner aggregates cannot specify a dataset scope. "**

I am at a loss on how to get the pareto to work

Answer (score 0):

If the sample is really your dataset results then I'm not sure you need to specify the scope at all.

Try removing the `, "Conf_Scrap"` from your expression.

If this does not work, your report design including any groups defined in the report and a larger sample if data (if applicable)